# Attempt to open browser in C++

Tags: c++, firefox, browser, system

I am attempting to open Firefox using C++ on Linux (Ubuntu). However, I get an segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong, and what should I do?

```
std::cout << system("/usr/bin/firefox") << std::endl;
```

Comment: What is the point of using std::cout?

Comment: Have you tried running your code under a debugger to determine *where* you are getting the segmentation fault?

Comment: @thrgle The path is fine
@Juliano Just to see what the output is, nothing else.
@Greg Hewgill When I run the program in debugger mode it works fine, but when I do not run it in debug mode, I get the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

It works fine, as posted a few times above. The problem was that I was using Netbeans. Netbeans caused a Segmentation Fault when trying to run it. Running outside Netbeans gave the expected result.

Nothing wrong with the code, just with Netbeans, strangely enough.

So everyone with the same error, try run it outside Netbeans.

Answer (score 4):

That code is correct.  It will output Firefox's termination code, with a newline.  Something else is causing your segmentation fault.

Comment: When I use a debugger to check my program, firefox starts, otherwise it just gives me a Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Try running /usr/bin/firefox in a command-line, and check if it works there. This looks like a problem with your firefox, not your code (the part you pasted is correct).